# Check if row already exists

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-insert

I want to check in my sql table if a row already existes.
I want to save data if it does not exists in my table. I'm using in select query but it doesn't work.

this is my code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO searchtable (word, position, count) VALUES (:word , :position, :count)";

$statement = $db->prepare($sql);


$temp="SELECT COUNT(word) AS searchtableFromword FROM  searchtable WHERE word=$title" ;

echo $temp;

if($temp== 0 )
{
    $statement->execute(array(
        'word' => $title,
        'position' => $fileNum,
        'count' => $titleVal
    ));
}
```

Comment: `mysql_num_rows`, `prepare`. Do you understand what happens in your code?

Comment: fixed it thanks but still have an error

Comment: You should learn the basics, you cant `mysql_num_rows($temp)` to a string

Comment: Even after your edit, you cant do this `$temp== 0 ` to a string

Comment: ok what I sould do?

Comment: It is impossible to insert a row in MySQL if it already exists so MySQL has you covered there.

Comment: it has to be executed first  `$result = $db->query($temp);`, then you can get your number of rows `$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IF you only want to insert a record when it does not exists, just use [INSERT IGNORE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

```
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO searchtable (word, position, count) VALUES (:word , :position, :count)";

$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
```

This will make sure that existing rows are left intact an a new one will be inserted if the record is absent.

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the
>   INSERT statement are ignored. For example, without IGNORE, a row that
>   duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table
>   causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With
>   IGNORE, the row is discarded and no error occurs. Ignored errors may
>   generate warnings instead, although duplicate-key errors do not.

Of course for this to be successful, you need a unique index on the the column of interest `word`

Comment: Its still save the data even if its alredy exists

Comment: For this to work, "word" should be either a primary key or unique key.

Comment: yes, just added that myself. I think your post and my update came simultanoues :) @MiguelGonzalez